# System monitor borders missing

Tags: unity, gnome, window-manager, window-decoration

It seems that some applications the borders are missing, I noticed it on [gnome-system-monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bce1q.png), but thought not much of it as I don't really use it. But more applications are having this issue too now, such as [gnome-clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XsRy.png). Any one any ideas what might be causing this? Most things work fine, e.g. [unity-control-center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzPJe.png).

EDIT: just found out, I can drag and drop it using the invisible areas (through the Alt modifier obviously).

Comment: If you notice the X in its top left corner, that should close it. I believe that some GNOME applications have changed in that they are doing this. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EEAn2TjKEARUJXcmM4czg2Szg/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to one of my screenshots, using `gnome-tweak-tool`. In my case, the button is on the right.

Comment: I would have understood a redesign, but have a look at another tab from the gnome-clock: http://i.imgur.com/14p4Jpz.png Yes, that's my background showing through the window. gnome-system-monitor is the same.